# Requirements for docking station to connect two external monitors to MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, dock

I want to buy a docking station to connect two external monitors (and some other stuff) to my MacBook Pro (2019 16'' i7). The monitors should **extend** the display, **not mirror** it, so that I have three independent monitors (2 external + MacBook Display).

From my research I thought it is sufficient, if the docking station has a Thunderbolt 3 connection to the MacBook (e.g. [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/407398/488270)). However, I bought [this docking station](https://icybox.de/en/product.php?id=5) which has Thunderbolt 3 but I am not able to connect both monitors to extend the display. My MacBook doesn't even show the second external monitor in the display settings, but it mirrors the first external monitor on the second one. I also clicked `Recognize monitors` in the display settings, but it didn't change a thing.

When I connect both monitors separately to the MacBook, I am able to get the result I want, but I want to use a docking station for convenience.

**What requirements does a docking station have to fulfill, so that I am able to achieve my goal?**

Comment: I don’t recall at the moment if the new MacBooks support Display Link (daisy chain displays). If your Mac doesn’t and your dock doesn’t, then you’ll need to plug each display into a separate port to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Allan if I understand [this](https://kb.plugable.com/docking-stations-and-video/does-plugable-support-macos-with-our-displaylink-based-products) correct, I can download [this](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/macos) so my Mac supports Display Link. Does my Mac AND my dock have to support Display Link?

Comment: Yes.  Everything from the source (MacBook) to the end-point (display) and everything in between must support it.

Comment: @Allan if you say end-point (display), you mean, that also my monitors have to support Display Link (is this even a thing?)? If so, how would I know?

Comment: If you’re daisy chaining them, yes.  The monitor will have two USB-C ports.  One in and the other out.  Thunderbolt works this way.  Usually the display was at the end because they didn’t daisy chain (at first)

Comment: I want to connect each external monitor to my docking station (one by HDMI, one by DisplayPort). Thats not daisy chaining then is it? So in this case they don't have to support it?

Comment: Each Type C port sends out one DP signal.  IF the dock doesn’t support DL, it won’t magically creat a second signal simply because you use both video ports even though they are different connectors. What you are seeing  is what describe - one video signal on two ports (extend on one and the other mirrors)

Comment: @Allan Yeah I got that. But is does it also depend on the external monitors or is it just depending on the Mac and the docking station?

Comment: If you need DL to daisy monitors without a dock, why wouldn’t you need DL for a dock that provides connections for monitors?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding: I know that my dock required DL. The question is if there is something like "support DL" for monitors too / if the monitors need to fulfill any requirements too, or if I can just connect any arbitrary monitors to the dock (which has DL).

Comment: Have you tried daisy chaining the monitors *without* the dock?  If you can't, for whatever reason, that monitor must either be last on the chain or on a separate port.

Comment: To daisy chain my monitors, they require Display Port 1.2 with Multi Stream Support. Both of my monitors don't have that.

But from my understanding, the monitors just display the input anyway, so the work has to be done in the docking station, to "split" the input from the MacBook to each output of the docking station, going to the corresponding monitor.

However it is, you already helped me a lot, thank you!